# Position button from 'Form' under a different div using 'flex'

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm having an issue with the positioning of a 'save' button under different div like the image below. I want to achive like in the image, 'Save' button from form under a different div.

[image]

Currently, what I have in the code is this:

```
export const StyledContainer = styled.div`
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 30px;

  input {
    width: 300px;
    height: 28px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
`;

 export const Styledinputs = styled.div`
   flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 13.5rem);
   flex-direction: column;
 `;

 export const StyledView = styled.div`
   padding: 5.5em 0;
 `;
```

The form code css is:

```
export const StyledTitle = styled.h2`
  padding: 32px 31px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
`;

 export const StyledForm = styled.div`
  width: 315px;
  height: 318px;
  padding: 0 31px;
  font-size: 13px;
 `;

 export const StyledButton = styled.div`
   padding-top: 10px;
 `;
```

Comment: Just make the form `width: 100%` and place the image inside of the form. That way you can align the button inside of the form.

Comment: not working as expected

Comment: Why are you using Flex? That looks like a job for Grid.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the library of final-form, there is an option of using "External Submit".
[Sample of external submit usage](https://codesandbox.io/s/1y7noyrlmq)

After implementing this, I've added the 'preview' component inside my 'Form' component, and when using 'flex' I was able to handle it very quick and simple.
The Form and Preview were with a parameter of - 'flex-direction': 'column'.